# PHP Login Form is misbehaving

Tags: php, post, get

There is an error in my php login script, but i have been unable to find it. can you explain to me how to debug this simple error.

here is my script:

```
session_start();

include("connect.php");

$kullanici = $_POST["user"];

$kullanici_sor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where isim = '{$user}'") or die (mysql_error)();

$admin = mysql_fetch_array($user_ask);

if($_POST["user"] == "" and $_POST["pass"] == "")
{
    echo "Cannot empty fields.Please tyr again!";
}else{
    if(isset($_POST["user"]))
    {
        if($_POST["user"]== $admin['name'] and ($_POST["pass"] == $admin['pass'])){
        $_SESSION["enter"] = true;
        $_SESSION["name"] =$_POST["user"];
        $_SESSION["pass"] =$_POST["pass"];
        header("Location: panel.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo"Wrong pass or username";
        header("refresh:2; url=index.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: you arent checking if the set of items `isset()` http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php

Comment: 1. Don't use deprecated function `mysql_*`. 2. Don't save the password in a session! 3. Why first check if `$_POST["user"]` is empty and after you check if it is set?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change your line:

```
$admin = mysql_fetch_array($user_ask);
```

info

```
$admin = mysql_fetch_array($kullanici_sor);
```

But your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements via PDO and not mysql. You should also at the beginning of your code (after `<?php` add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

when you are testing your script. On production it should be set to:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors','0');
```

**EDIT** And of course as someone mentioned in comment you should never put your password into session!

Answer (score 0):

```
$kullanici_sor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where isim = '{$user}'") or die (mysql_error)();

$admin = mysql_fetch_array($kullanici_sor);
```

Comment: While the code-change you supplied should fix the, if it's the only, issue, it's not very apparent by your answer. Could you update your answer to include an actual explanation to help the OP and others understand what you've done and how to fix the problem?